# Static referencing error

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beginner Java - Static Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774376/beginner-java-static-error)

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        char[] b = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'};
        int p = 4;
        deleteRepeats(b, p);
    }

    public void deleteRepeats(char[] a, int size) {
        int currentElement;
        currentElement = 0;
        do {
            for (int i = currentElement; i < size-1; i++) {
                if (a[currentElement] == a[i+1]) a[i+1] = ' ';
            }
            currentElement++;
        } while (currentElement < size-1);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> non-static method deleteRepeats(char[],int) cannot be referenced from a static context deleteRepeats(b,p);

Can someone tell me what this means?

I tried removing  "static" from the main method, but I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the links in the sidebar to the right. There are literally hundreds of duplicates of this question.

Comment: JVM needs the main() to be static, so it could call it without object to enclosing class. YOU CANT REMOVE STATIC there, Only @JonSkeet can do so. (#JSFACTS)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `deleteRepeats` be a *class method*:

```
//Note the "static"
public static void deleteRepeats(char[] a, int size) {
    //...
}
```

Class methods can be invoked without having an object to invoke them on. Methods that are declared without `static` are called *instance methods* and they must be invoked on an object:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    private int instanceField = 10;
    private static int classField = 30;
    //Main is initially invoked without creating an object
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //So it is only possible to call methods that do not require an object,
        classMethodExample();
        //until an object is created...
        HelloWorld helloWorldObject = new HelloWorld();
        //at which point it becomes possible to call
        //member functions on that object
        helloWorldObject.instanceMethodExample();
        //Modify "helloWorldObject", and call instanceMethodExample again.
        helloWorldObject.instanceField = 20;
        helloWorldObject.instanceMethodExample();
    }
    public static void classMethodExample() {
        //Not invoked on an object, so cannot access instanceField
        //Can access classField
        System.out.println(classField); //prints "30"
    }

    public void instanceMethodExample() {
        //Can access instanceField within helloWorldObject
        System.out.println(instanceField); //prints "10" on the first call,
                                           //"20" on the second call
        //Can also access classField
        System.out.println(classField); //prints "30"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove static form main method which is the java standard way. you can remove it then it is just a method. You coulden't run the program.

To talk to your

```
 public void deleteRepeats(char[] a, int size)
```

method

1) You can make it as static and call in main method

```
 public static  void deleteRepeats(char[] a, int size)
```

your main method now,

```
  public static void main(String [] args){
         char[] b = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'};
        int p=4;
        deleteRepeats(b,p);
    }
```

2) or else you can use  deleteRepeats method as it is and call in the main method by creating a object of that,

in this way

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();
         char[] b = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'};
        int p=4;
        hello.deleteRepeats(b,p);
    }
```

Comment: This question has numerous duplicates. Instead of answering duplicates and increasing redundancy you should share link to duplicate in question. 
PS : That wont earn you reputation though. !!